# React-Select: Is there a way to pass options props as children Option Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Hello I am working on implementing a react-select component and I would like to pass options as children like this:

```
<Select>
 <Option value="0">Red</Option>
 <Option value="1">Blue</Option>
 <Option value="2">Green</Option>
 <Option value="3">Yellow</Option>
</Select>
```

is equal to:

```
const options = [
  { value: "0", label: "Red" },
  { value: "1", label: "Blue" },
  { value: "2", label: "Green" },
  { value: "3", label: "Yellow" },
];
<Select options={options}/>
```

Is it possible ?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't it is possible to pass Options as children as there is no example showing this sort of API in docs. But If you want to customize `Options` component, that can be easily done.

Comment: yes that's what I thought... thanks